# Securing a private RSA key for distribution

Tags: rsa, sha

There's a new law concerning POS systems in Norway which comes into effect 1.1.2017 starting that:

> b. Private Key – is secured by the system vendor, only the vendor knows the key.
>   c. Public Key – is sent to The Tax Authorities "

This law states that POS machines have to hash and sign certain data that then gets logged to electronic journal. Their information letter specifically says that data should be signed using private key.

This in turn means that the private key somehow has to exist in every copy of the POS software so that it can sign hashes even if the customer's internet goes down.

If one encrypted it, the key for decrypting still have to exist in the client program..

Is there any way to properly secure a private key for distribution in a client software?

Comment: what do you mean by "secure"? you don't have to use the key for anything besides signing, so what's the harm of it's revelation?

Comment: "secure for distribution"? That needs a lot more explanation. How to distribute? How to keep the key secure after being distributed across many clients? How to secure the key on the client? Can you not use a unique key per client?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

Schroeder: The law around this is not 100% finalized, but as of right now it looks like it's 1 key per supplier.

Which means if I have 100 customers with 2 POS machines each there will be 200 copies of the private key out there.

Answer (score 4):

Its done by using a "Smart card" tamper resistant storage chip, so the key can only be "used", not "extracted". If any attempt is made to attack the chip to reveal the key, different sensors will react and erase the chip as soon as it is powered up.

The sensor is usually one-shot, eg when a specific condition is met, the sensor is permanently tripped, so as soon as the power is applied, it will detect that the sensor is tripped and erase the key.

The key is also stored in a way so it practically becomes impossible to extract the key using passive methods while the chip is offline.

Propably the chip will also include battery and a trusted clock, to prevent tampering, so it can also detect any tampering "offline".

This chip will propably be part of a hardware device that must be used in conjuction with the POS system, either embedded, or if its a software POS, a USB key or something inserted in the USB port.

The reason a key scheme is used, is to prevent someone from creating a fake journal that is a exact copy for the genuine journal except that certain records is changed.

Here in sweden a similiar scheme is used, but instead of requiring each POS vendor to gain a key, a "journal box", that is compatible with all POS system is used. This journal box signs data in roughtly the same way, and a verification code is shown on receipt, but the difference is that only the "journal box" vendors need to be "trusted".

And no, theres no requirement for a offline signing system. The vendor can simply require online-signing for software-only solutions if no hardware is to be distributed, and then if the internet is down, then its simple as "you are not permitted to sell, period".
A similiar rule is here in sweden if theres a power outage. Not allowed to sell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth comment about how it is in Sweden. 
In Norway there is no law requiring us to have a box like you do.
I'm sorry to say, but no internet == no sale is never gonna happen.. 

Power outage == no sale? What? You don't have UPS'es in Sweden? :D hehe.. 

But joke aside, the system of course have to be able to be used even if offline, thus the private key must reside client side.
If it was online only then the key could be kept on my server and signing/hashing could be done via webservice.